# golang - HTTP client always escaped the URL

Tags: http, go

Is there anyway for golang HTTP client,not to escape the requested URL.
For example, a request for URL "/test(a)", gets escaped to "/test%28a%29".
I'm running the code from https://github.com/cmpxchg16/gobench

Comment: URL Encoding is one of the responsibilities of the client. And you can decode on the receiving end (or the server already decodes the URL for you).

Comment: I know, the problem is that currently the server doesn't handle encoded urls (i don't have any access to it). For testing purposes, i'm asking if there is anyway to disable the url escaping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set an opaque url.

Assuming you want the url to point to `http://example.com/test(a)` you would want to do:

```
req.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/test(a)", nil)
req.URL = &url.URL{
    Scheme: "http",
    Host:   "example.com",
    Opaque: "//example.com/test(a)",
}
client.Do(req)
```

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/09V67Hbo6H

Documentation: http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL

Comment: Great, it works for me, although the solution was a bit obscure, sorry I mean opaque :p

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the URL package:

https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6784

and https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5684

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [Unescaped Path](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#PathUnescape) to URL Path and Encoded Path to RawURL or else it will double escape e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    doubleEncodedURL := &url.URL{
        Scheme: "http",
        Host:   "example.com",
        Path:   "/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%2BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%2FEGs7f/events",
    }

    rawEncodedURL := &url.URL{
        Scheme:  "http",
        Host:    "example.com",
        Path:    "/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa+IFVla4ZdfRiMzfh/EGs7f/events",
        RawPath: "/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%2BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%2FEGs7f/events",
    }

    fmt.Printf("doubleEncodedURL is : %s\n", doubleEncodedURL)
    fmt.Printf("rawEncodedURL is    : %s\n", rawEncodedURL)

}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/rOrVzW8ZJCQ