# Escape exclamation mark in http request

Tags: http, go, escaping

I have a URL like

```
http://app.chat.com/avert!Callbcak.htm
```

to request.

I created the request with golang

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://app.chat.com/avert!Callbcak.htm", nil)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", req.URL.String())
```

result is

```
http://app.chat.com/avert%21Callbcak.htm
```

which is not going to work, the website needs URL that exclamation mark not escaped.

How can I request that URL correctly?

Comment: Exclamation mark (!) is a reserved character, and "If a reserved character is found in a URI component and no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that character's encoding in US-ASCII" [(RFC3986)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2). For the `http` URI scheme, there is no known usage for !, so escaping it should be okay. In your case it isn't though. Maybe someone might have an answer.

Comment: `http://app.chat.com/avert!Callbcak.htm` is not an URL.

Comment: @Volker: Why isn't it an URL? Does the spec require you to encode `!`?  I though the spec meant that it should be interpreted in the same way as `%21`

Comment: There are all kinds of punctuation characters but ! is not listed http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp.

Comment: @Volker: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 says path segments are made up of `*pchar`, where `pchar` is `unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"`.  `sub-delims` includes `"!"` among other characters, so it is valid according to that RFC, at least.

Comment: @James: You're right. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847357/golang-http-client-always-escaped-the-url/20847921#20847921)

I process the request before sending:

```
func (s *Sender) regulateRequestURL(req *http.Request) {
    if strings.Contains(req.URL.Path, "!") {
        req.URL.Opaque = fmt.Sprintf("//%s%s", req.URL.Host, req.URL.Path)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

> Section 2, on characters, has been rewritten to explain what
> characters are reserved, when they are reserved, and why they are
> reserved, even when they are not used as delimiters by the generic
> syntax. The mark characters that are typically unsafe to decode,
> including the exclamation mark ("!"), asterisk ("*"), single-quote
> ("'"), and open and close parentheses ("(" and ")"), have been moved
> to the reserved set in order to clarify the distinction between
> reserved and unreserved and, hopefully, to answer the most common
> question of scheme designers.  Likewise, the section on
> percent-encoded characters has been rewritten, and URI normalizers
> are now given license to decode any percent-encoded octets

This means that `!` is an unfortunate choice of a separator because although the grammar allows its use in `segment` (as part of the `pchar` non-terminal) it is also a part of the `reserved` non-terminal.

As I read it the RFC is slightly ambivalent about `!` *reservedness*, depending upon the context in which it is used.

Escaping the character seems the most safe assumption to make since the recipient is "licenced to decode the percent-encoded octet". You should consider using another separator or decoding the entity on the endpoint.

Comment: thank you for your explaination, the URL is from our client, they use something like struts ~